# 5 different Objects with the same values to an function

Tags: c#, oop, object, xsd

I have created a Structure class with the "XSD.exe" and now I have a short problem:

I have 5 different "Classes" in the Structure and all 5 Classes have the same values like this:

```
public partial class Carrier
{

    private string codeField;

    private string companyField;

    private string legalNameField;

    private string addressField;

    private string address2Field;

    private string stateField;

    private string cityField;

    private string countryField;

    private string phoneField;

    private string faxField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return this.companyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.companyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string LegalName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.legalNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.legalNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return this.addressField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.addressField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Address2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.address2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.address2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string State
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Country
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Phone
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.phoneField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Fax
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faxField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faxField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want set all five different object to another object like this:

```
 private Adress FindAddresses(Carrier address)
    {
        tempAddress = new Address();
        tempAddress.AddressCode = address.Code;
        tempAddress.Name1 = address.LegalName;
        tempAddress.Name2 = address.Address;
        tempAddress.Name3 = address.Address2;
        return tempAddress;
    }
```

Is the only way to do this to overload this function 5 times or gives an "better" way to do this ?

Comment: I can't see what five objects you are talking about.

Comment: I dont want do copy all 5 in this because they have all the same fields...the "Carrier" is only the example...all 5 have the same fields but another "Classnam"

Comment: Why do you have five distinct but identical classes?

Comment: Could be that he as a `Carrier`, a `Shipper`, a `Destination` etc., all of them containing address fields.

Comment: Because i read an XML file and all notes will get to an fully filled object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let the classes implement the same interface, for example `IAdressable`:

```
public interface IAddressable
{
    public AddressCode Code { get; set; }
    public string LegalName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now the method could take an `IAddressable` as argument:

```
 private Adress FindAddresses(IAddressable address)
{
    var tempAddress = new Address();
    tempAddress.AddressCode = address.Code;
    tempAddress.Name1 = address.LegalName;
    tempAddress.Name2 = address.Address;
    tempAddress.Name3 = address.Address2;
    return tempAddress;
}
```

Then you can call this method with all your classes since they all implement that interface.

Comment: That's a nice idea, thank you! Better than overload a function 5 or more times :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move the common properties into a common base class and derive `Carrier` and the 4 other classes from that base class.

The methods would then take an instance of the base class.

```
public class BaseAddressClass
{
    ...
}

public class Carrier : BaseAddressClass
{
    // Other fields
}

private Address FindAddress(BaseAddressClass address)
{
    ...
}
```